# Restoring automatic selection of natural gas heat vs. heat pump based on outdoor temperature

Tags: hvac, thermostat, heat-pump, usa

I had a Goodman SSZ14 series heat pump installed in 2008, with the installation came a then top-o-the-line Honeywell thermostat which provided the feature to select heating source (heat pump or natural gas furnace) based on outdoor air temperature.  This feature was to minimize heating costs as well as protect the heat pump from running in temperatures cold enough to damage it.  The heat pump is still running fine but the thermostat that could automatically select heat from the heat pump or the furnace has died, this is an important feature since this was not only to minimize heating costs but was the only thing protecting the heat pump from cold weather damage.  In the mean time I figured out how to get the heat pump to run for cooling and the furnace to run for heating.

If I have heating and cooling then what is the problem?  That was hinted at above, I get no cost savings on having the heat pump provide heat unless I risk running it in outdoor temperatures cold enough to damage it.  How often does it get cold enough to damage the heat pump?  I don't know exactly, I can't find information on how cold it must get to damage the heat pump.  All I know is that if I operate the heat pump for optimal cost savings the delta on that temperature was large enough that optimizing for cost was considered sufficient for protections from cold.  Or so it seems as there's no provisions for cold weather protections in the heat pump, only the thermostat provided this protection, and (again) the thermostat died.

What have I done so far in looking for a resolution?  I'll explain, and I know what follows is long but the details are important.

First step was I searched for off the shelf thermostats with the desired functionality.  Not knowing any specific name for this feature I looked for things like "heat pump compatible", "outdoor temperature sensor", and "automatic backup heat".  I can find thermostats with all these features all day but none will automatically switch to the natural gas furnace should outdoor temperatures fall below a specified limit.  If there is an automated switchover feature in the thermostat then they rely on systems in the heat pump to perform this function, and my heat pump has none.  Maybe I missed something obvious but I'm not finding a thermostat with the right features.  Is there a specific word or phrase I should be searching for?

Next step was to check with Honeywell on a replacement, perhaps the same 15+ year old model I had or something newer with equivalent features.  The specific model I had is no longer made and the replacement model was only offered to licensed HVAC installers.  I didn't want to call any HVAC installer because the entire point is DIY for cost savings, and replacing a thermostat was something I felt confident in doing myself.

Perhaps Goodman had some useful information on solving my problem?  Checking their website I found spec sheets that verified that there was no cold temperature switchover function built into the heat pump unit, and that Goodman didn't specify how cold the heat pump could get before failure so I'd feel confident that the heat pump was not at risk of failure if I forgot to switch to the furnace manually when cold weather was a threat.  This isn't too surprising, while heat pumps have existed for a long time it is relatively recent that people were concerned about running them in cold (as opposed to merely "cool") weather.  Also, Goodman indicated on their website that they do not provide support to homeowners, only licensed HVAC installers.

Okay, fine, I'll call a f**king installer.

The people that installed my heat pump were willing to perform a thermostat replacement but at a price I found to be quite high.  A price high enough that I could likely get a new heat pump installed, granted not a heat pump as powerful as what I have now but powerful enough for some definitions of "enough".  The goal isn't having a heat pump, it is saving on heating costs with the side benefit of something to backup the furnace.  I don't know if I'd save enough money on natural gas fuel from with heating from a heat pump unless the repairs were very minimal in cost, and I know I can get backup heating at a price lower than what was quoted for a repair.  I asked the HVAC installer if they'd sell me the thermostat so I could install it myself.  Nope.  Makes sense, they aren't Home Depot, they make their money on installations.

I could keep calling HVAC installers but I expect much the same response.  I could ask someone wearing an orange apron on product options but I expect the same problems with my own searches, without some specific term to search on they will come up empty.  I really just need the right kind of thermostat, one that someone is willing to sell to the general public, and not at some sky high price.  What is "sky high"?  Well, there's some very nice "smart" thermostats for less than $300 so above that is one definition.  Can I find one of these "installer special" thermostats online at discount prices?  I assume so but if the thermostat is used or from some fly-by-night shop then I have no customer support, and no assurance it functions as promised.

So, before I give up completely I thought I'd post here for ideas.  I know asking for product suggestions is at least discouraged but this may be unavoidable since the product selection with the required function is likely small.  Again that function is to switch from a heat pump to a natural gas furnace without any indication from the heat pump that it is operating in an unsafe and/or inefficient manner.  What is considered safe and efficient can be indicated by measuring outdoor temperature as my old thermostat did but I've seen heat pumps that make this distinction based on refrigerant pressure at certain points in the coolant loop, but there's no such sensors in my heat pump.

Comment: What is the model # of the old thermostat?

Comment: "What is the model # of the old thermostat?"  I'm reluctant to provide that information assuming I can find it.  The thermostat was quite old so it's hardly something I'd want again, and Honeywell isn't supporting it any more.  The thermostat is now in a landfill but if I dig long enough in my installer notes I could possibly find the model number again.  The thermostat was about 15 years old when it died, it first came to market years prior, and hasn't been made new for years.  There's likely some new-old-stock floating about, and almost certainly used, but I just don't want that model again.

Comment: My reason for asking is **not** to go hunting for the same model on eBay. My reason is because looking at the manual and/or specifications might provide keywords/terminology that would be useful in searching for a replacement. I am pretty sure I understand what you're looking for, but the description you have provided may or may not match industry standard terminology, which may be complicating the search.

Comment: I found what appears to be the install guide for my old thermostat, it could also be from helping my brother install something similar many years ago.  So ***a*** model number is "THM5421C" with what appears to be the name of the product series "VisionPRO IAQ".

Comment: Aren't you basically running a "heat pump plus auxiliary heat" system?  Pretty much any modern smart (maybe even dumb) thermostat should run that, no?

Comment: You've got a great answer for your exact problem (I +1'ed). However, I'd suggest you at least think about "smart home" automation of this. AIUI, smart home setup increases potential sales price as well as making things nicer for you. A simple set up would be a 'stat for the heat pump and a separate one for the furnace. Logic is `IF outdoorTemp > <setpoint>, turn on HP ELSE turn on furnace`.  Something to think about... You don't even need your own outdoor thermometer - most home automation can pick up official weather for your area which should be close enough.

Comment: @Huesmann  Most any $30 thermostat will safely operate my heat pump  but only as an air conditioner.  Most any $50 thermostat will operate the furnace and allow the heat pump to provide heating and cooling but that means there's nothing protecting the heat pump from running itself to the point of destruction in cold weather.  There's $100 thermostats that will at least claim they can switch from heat pump to furnace and back for maximum savings on fuel and electricity but they rely on the heat pump to indicate it is too cold to run safely and efficiently, my heat pump doesn't do that.

Comment: @FreeMan  Having separate thermostats for heat pump and furnace would be bad, that removes any communication on which heat source is providing heat and blasting hot air from the furnace on the heat pump coils would almost certainly break something very expensive.  Also, a mishap on settings for each thermostat could mean cooling and heating are running at the same time, also bad.  The entire problem is locating a thermostat of any kind that do as you describe, "smart home" or not.  If I have to pay an installer to put one in then that is a money pit the heat pump might not be able to fill in.

Comment: @MacGuffin so you're looking for "cheap" and not "pricey but works?"

Comment: "removes any communication on which heat source is providing..." that's where the home automation comes into play. Basically using some HA allows you to put together _exactly_ what you're looking for and to tailor it _exactly_ the way you want it, even if you can no longer find a single device that does exactly what you want. Wanted to toss it out as an idea for you to contemplate - if you don't like it, well, don't contemplate it any longer...

Comment: @Huesmann  I'm looking for a thermostat in the sub-$300 range without the installer 2x to 3x markup for installation I could almost certainly do myself.  If it's a really *really* nice thermostat then I'd be willing to pay more, but I'd still want to get it without the installer markup.  At some point the cost of the thermostat is a debt that would not be paid back (not in any reasonable time anyway) by enabling use of cheaper electricity over natural gas.  What I have now *works* but it's merely not *ideal*, so that also puts a low ceiling on the price I'm willing to pay.

Comment: @FreeMan  Home automation thermostats are great but none I've seen, with rare exceptions I'll get back to, would allow for using outdoor temperature to impact function.  They'd show the temperature outside on the display, but they would not use that information for anything else.  One exception to this rule is thermostats from an installer, but that costs more than it's worth, unless the installer is also coming out to do some other repairs perhaps.  The other exception is new models that just came on the market, and I missed them until pointed out to me in the last couple days.

Comment: @MacGuffin have you looked at the ecobee thermostat?

Comment: @Huesmann  Yes, I've looked at the ecobee thermostat.  Unless something has changed they don't select heat source based on outdoor temperatures.

Comment: @MacGuffin not sure what you're talking about.  My (now old) ecobee has a setting that will run the compressor only if the outdoor temperature is above whatever temperature you set.  If the temp falls below that, only AUX will run.  Menu>Settings>Installation Settings>Thresholds>Compressor Min Outdoor Temp.  "This is set at a default 35F (1.7C), so the heatpump will not be used when the weather outside is below 35 degrees Fahrenheit and only aux heat will be used in this case."  I'm sure the outdoor temp is determined from the Internet, and not locally, but still, there is such a setting.

Comment: @Huesmann  I called ecobee support and they said the temperature was from the internet, and if internet was lost then it would default to running the heat pump.  There's still a fallback to AUX heat if too much time has passed for the temperature to climb so at least the *house* won't freeze but that's not protecting the *heat pump* from cold temperatures.  If there was a default to AUX if internet was lost then that would protect the heat pump, since the need for heat tends to coincide with loss of internet access I'm reluctant to consider that safe.

Comment: I mean, if the internet goes out and *you* decide—based on whatever method of temperature determination—that it's too cold for your heat pump, perhaps you can just turn off the breaker for the heat pump.  I guess it depends how your system is wired up.  I doubt you're gonna find a thermostat with a hardwired thermometer.

Comment: @Huesmann  The point is to not have to "babysit" the heat pump.  I can already flip switches and push buttons to select where I get my heat.  I don't want to have my heat pump destroyed because there was an unexpected cold snap or power outage while I was away from home or sleeping.  The point of a heat pump is primarily to lower heating costs, and it can't do that if I keep disabling it out of an abundance of caution, or I toss all caution to the wind only to have it run for days in a pointless attempt to heat the house during a cold snap and destroy itself in the process.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why it has been so hard to figure this out. My guess is that Honeywell is only interested in Honeywell products (*though it may turn out they have something that will do exactly what you want*) and installers are only interested in installing full systems. In any case, a few minutes of searching and here you go:

[AprilAire S86NMUPR Programmable Multistage Universal Thermostat](https://amzn.to/44jtop5). Picture from Amazon (but you can buy it plenty of different places):

[image: AprilAire thermostat]

The important details are in the [installation instructions](https://www.discounthomeautomation.com/discounthomeautomation/products/pdf/RP-AprilAire/AprilAire_S86NMU-S86NMUPR_Multi-Stage_Universal_Thermostat_Safety_and_Installation_Instructions.pdf). See page 4:

> **OUTDOOR TEMPERATURE SENSOR (INCLUDED WITH S86N MUPR ONLY)**
>
> Outdoor temperature can be measured by attaching the included 8052 sensor to the T1 and T2 terminals. The outdoor sensor must be enabled in the installer setup menu.
>
> **Heat pump models can use the outdoor temperature to effectively utilize the heat pump:**
>
> - When the outdoor temperature is lower than the Low Balance Point, the heat pump will be locked out and only auxiliary heating will be used to provide heating.
> - When the outdoor temperature is higher than the High Balance Point, the auxiliary heating will be locked out and only the heat pump will be used to provide heating.

So essentially you can pick the temperature (High Balance Point, default 65 F) where only the Heat Pump runs and the temperature (Low Balance Point, default 20 F) where only Aux. Heat runs. Presumably in between other rules will apply based on how the system is configured.

**Enjoy your new thermostat.**

*I have no connection with AprilAire, and I would be surprised if there were not at least 3 other thermostat manufacturers with a comparable feature readily available.*

Comment: "I don't know why it has been so hard to figure this out."  My guess is that it's because that model didn't exist until a couple or three months ago, it was not in the places I looked yet.  Thanks for that.  I'd like to know what search terms and such you used to find this, I'd like to shop around for different models if possible before buying anything.

Comment: I don't remember exactly. Something like: *multi-stage thermostat with remote outdoor sensors*. But since it was around 15+ years ago in a Honeywell, I don't think the AprilAire is inherently new, just that particular product line.

Comment: The feature isn't new, obviously, it's just not common.  I have a theory on why I had such difficulty finding this feature before but it's not going to fit in this comment box.  A summary might be that there's no standard on how heat pumps are supposed to work yet, so most thermostat makers just left that to the heat pump and the thermostat I had was an early adopter rarity.  With heat pumps being more popular, and "smart" thermostats being more popular, there's something of a standard to work from now. I looked on and off for months for a thermostat that would work for me and I found nothing.

Comment: "Something like: multi-stage thermostat with remote outdoor sensors."  I searched with those terms before but I believe I gave up on using "multi-stage" because that was just muddying the waters with with too many things for resistance heating.  Looking at the product description the key words to look for might be "low balance point".

Comment: The reason you saw things about "resistance heating" is that if someone installed a heat pump in a new house, or as a replacement for a really old system (e.g., boiler/radiators) then putting in resistance heat as the backup for really cold days is the norm. Retrofits into houses with functioning natural gas furnaces is something far more common now because thanks to improved efficiency (COP), where a heat pump typically wasn't that much more efficient than natural gas even at moderate temperatures, now they can be far more efficient and even at colder temperatures. But as far as the

Comment: thermostat is concerned, "resistance heat" or "natural gas furnace" or "boiler" are all **exactly the same thing** - a heat source turned on at a certain point when the heat pump is not able to do the job (which usually means "too cold outside").

Comment: In some additional searching, I am 98% certain that there are a couple of current lines of Honeywell thermostats that handle outdoor sensors perfectly well. The problem is that they are limiting them to professional installers. I understand the "professional installer" concept in certain respects, but while I think it actually makes sense for some things (e.g., the actual heat pumps, because of refrigerant, furnaces because of gas, etc.) thermostats are a place where DIY is ideal - low voltage, almost always nice colored wires to match up, etc. Honeywell is throwing away some of the market

Comment: where they really could compete with Nest, etc.

Comment: "The reason you saw things about "resistance heating" is that..."  I believe it is because with resistance heat people like to stage the heating elements so the lights don't dim when the heat comes on, so that the heating power can be varied by powering up just 1 or 2 elements instead of all 3 or 4, in addition to the reason stated that resistance heat is commonly paired with heat pumps.  The problem is that some places made a distinction between "multi-stage" (meaning 3 or 4) and "2-stage".  I needed at least 2-stage so if I search on "multi-stage" then I could be filtering out valid results.